# Writing code or finding C libraries for database like features?

Tags: c

For a few years now I have been working on a system that currently stores its data in a database. It has quite a high demand on it with millions of transactions.

There is no *need* to do this but purely for fun I have been for a long time now wondering just how fast I could make it if I wrote the whole thing in c, and writing/reading directly from disk. I know this is a little crazy.

All of the data fits in memory, so the biggest issue is going to be somehow storing a transaction log that can be replayed if the system crashes.

I am wondering what people with more experience in C than I think about this.

Comment: Writing stuff in C doesn't automatically make it faster.

Comment: Don't believe I was suggesting using C automatically makes things faster. (:

Comment: That's how your "question" reads. I also voted to close this - you don't have a specific/practical programming question here.

Comment: I don't think it will be considerable faster. At least as long as it has to write stuff to disk.

Comment: Ok, where do you go to ask for this sort of advise? Thanks

Comment: We honestly don't understand your question. This is the right place, but your question, as it currently stands, makes no sense and isn't asking something that can be definitively answered. That said, look at BDB.

Comment: @Jacob nobody can answer that question for you with the details given. You have a database (could be for example a cluster running Oracle) with unspecified table structure and type of queries, and you're wondering if a C program doing disk access can outperform it. That really depends on too many variables, like how well your disk accesses fit in disk cache, how many random seeks are going on and what type of disk it is.

Comment: Just to get an estimate, you could compile postgresql with profiling enabled, run a typical query, stop the server, and do the aftermath (which will be a lot of work). You'll need to differentiate between true "executor" code and glue code. The executor itself would probably be a factor X (10...100) faster if every execution plan were hardcoded. Note: maybe you'll have to switch off inlining, too ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand he question correctly, I can see two options:

1. You could look at something like SQLite, which gives both the "written in C" and fast execution parts, in addition to handling your storage to disk.  It is a file-based database and is very fast and resilient against system/program crashes.
2. You could log all your data to disk while storing the live copy, but if you store it as SQL transactions, it is going to be larger than the equivalent raw data.  In this case you have a trade-off in that something like SQLite will likely have more processing overhead than your hand coded RAM storage method, but may have less to write to disk due to its raw (non-SQL) storage.